# Can't create database or stored procedure in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to create a customer database app in Visual Studio, but my VS2015 doesn't show the option to create tables or stored procedure on my local database. I tried to use an Access database but I had the same problem.

There is any way to do it? Or it isn't a feature in Community version? Thanks!

Comment: Here are the differences between versions: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/. I don't understand what you are trying to do, can you be more explicit? What do you mean by your 'local database'? Are you using Server Explorer in VS?

Comment: I can't create tables when I create a local database directly from VS. There is no option to this on the right-click menu, just "refresh" and "properties". Anyway, I solved my problem with an external db using Access.